# Adding start, stop, and reset buttons for a timer

Tags: javascript

I'm making a timer and have it working already one load. I want to add a start, stop, and reset button to it. This is my code as is atm.

```
    (function() {
         "use strict";
         var secondsLabel = document.getElementById('seconds'),
         minutesLabel = document.getElementById('minutes'),
         hoursLabel = document.getElementById('hours'),
         totalSeconds = 0,
         startButton = document.getElementById('start'),
         resetButton = document.getElementById('reset'),
         onOff = 0; 
         startButton.onclick = function() {
         onOff = 1;
     };
     resetButton.onclick = function() {
         totalSeconds = 0;
         onOff = 0;
     };

     if ( onOff == 1 ) {
         setInterval( setTime, 1000 );
         function setTime() {
         totalSeconds++;
         secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad( totalSeconds % 60 );
         minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad( parseInt( totalSeconds / 60 ) );
         hoursLabel.innerHTML = pad( parseInt( totalSeconds / 3600 ) )
     }
     function pad( val ) {
         var valString = val + "";
         if( valString.length < 2 ) {
            return "0" + valString;
         } else {
            return valString;
         }
     }
   }

 })();
```

The buttons are not working atm however. I'm not sure if this the best solution for the goal as well, so suggestions are welcome.

Comment: this.tId=setInterval... now you can do clearInterval(this.tId) to stop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(function() {
  "use strict";
  var secondsLabel = document.getElementById('seconds'), minutesLabel = document.getElementById('minutes'), hoursLabel = document
      .getElementById('hours'), totalSeconds = 0, startButton = document.getElementById('start'), stopButton = document.getElementById('stop'), resetButton = document
      .getElementById('reset'), timer = null;

  startButton.onclick = function() {
    if (!timer) {
      timer = setInterval(setTime, 1000);
    }
  };

  stopButton.onclick = function() {
    if (timer) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      timer = null;
    }
  };

  resetButton.onclick = function() {
    if (timer) {
      totalSeconds = 0;
      stop();
    }
  };

  function setTime() {
    totalSeconds++;
    secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds % 60);
    minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
    hoursLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 3600))
  }

  function pad(val) {
    var valString = val + "";
    if (valString.length < 2) {
      return "0" + valString;
    } else {
      return valString;
    }
  }

})();
```

Comment: How could I stop the timer.

Comment: either click the reset button or create another function that does the clearInterval() like stop() function

Comment: What would I add to the startButton() so I can resume the timer if I pushed stop?

Comment: I added a stop function. No change to startButton

Comment: Just for usability I tried to reset the seconds, minutes, and hours to 00 like so:    secondsLabel.innerHTML = 00;
   minutesLabel.innerHTML = 00;
   hoursLabel.innerHTML = 00;. It didn't work, why so?

Comment: Are 00 in quotes like "00"?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var c=0;
var t;
var timer_is_on=0;

function timedCount()
{
document.getElementById('txt').value=c;
c=c+1;
t=setTimeout("timedCount()",1000);
}

function doTimer()
{
if (!timer_is_on)
  {
  timer_is_on=1;
  timedCount();
  }
}

function stopCount()
{
clearTimeout(t);
timer_is_on=0;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Start count!" onclick="doTimer()" />
<input type="text" id="txt" />
<input type="button" value="Stop count!" onclick="stopCount()" />
</form>
<p>
Click on the "Start count!" button above to start the timer. The input field will count forever, starting at 0. Click on the "Stop count!" button to stop the counting. Click on the "Start count!" button to start the timer again.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To add a reset button would I set the c = 0?