# How to start ajax request periodically use jquery every 10 second after click button?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to fetch last record from database I've wrote a Action Method (that name is GetData) in `HomeController` and it is has to fetch data and return based on `jsonResult` on view.but I want to after click on button ajax reuqest every 10 second to GetData Action method when I click on another button for stoping ajax. 
My code isn't working right now.

```
    public JsonResult GetData()
    {
        var fetchData = db.Scraps.Max(s => (int?)s.Id) ?? 0;
        var findData = db.Scraps.Find(fetchData);
        return Json(findData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

---

```
<script>

    $(function () {

        $("#btnStart").click(function () {
            setTimeout(executeQuery, 10000);
        });

    });

        function executeQuery() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Home/GetData",
                data: {},
                success: function (data) {
                    var rows = "<tr>" + "<td>" + data.Url + "</td>" + "<td>" + data.Keyword + "</td>" + "<td>" + data.DateTime + "</td>" + "<td>" + data.Count + "<td/>" + "</tr>";
                    $("#scrapTable tbody").append(rows);
                    //alert(data.Url);
                    console.log(data.Url + ":" + data.DateTime + ":" + data.Keyword + ":" + data.Count);

                }

            });
        }


</script>
```

---

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("index", "home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    ....
    <button type="submit" id="btnStart" class="btn btn-success">Start</button>
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @StephenMuecke,I wrote my code but It didn't work I want to work executeQuery every 10 second .after that click on button

Comment: Then you need to explain that in your question - what is currently happening, what is not working etc?

Comment: you can use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` for repeated process and `clearInterval` to stop it. However, i feel it would be better to wait for the request to finish, and that it could be `executeQuery` that starts another timeout when it finishes

Comment: Refer also the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121766/adding-start-stop-and-reset-buttons-for-a-timer) for typical implementation

Comment: Again - what is not working? Is you script even being executed (you have not shown us your button element with `id="btnStart') What errors are you getting in the browser console etc

Comment: @StephenMuecke,I've added html code

Comment: And is your ajax code being executed?, and is your controller method being hit? - you need to debug your code and tell us what is not working!

Comment: @StephenMuecke,I founded my problem I've use a button that submit my form to index action and I use it for ajax request.

Comment: Therefore the code should be `$("#btnStart").click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); setTimeout(executeQuery, 10000); })` so that you cancel the default submit (or just use `<button type="button" ...`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a empty variable and then assign a `setInterval` function to it on the click event.

In this example, just replace the `console.log('Run Every 10 Seconds');` with `executeQuery();`

This can then be cleared using `clearInterval(timeoutFunction)` on another buttons click event.

For example:

```js
$(function () {

var timeoutFunction;

$("#btnStart").click(function () {
  timeoutFunction = setInterval(function(){
  //executeQuery();
  console.log('Run Every 10 Seconds');
  }, 10000);
});

$("#btnStop").click(function () {
  clearInterval(timeoutFunction);
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btnStart">Start</button>
<button id="btnStop">Stop</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to use [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) instead of settimout , also wrap the call of function inside a function block ,see below working fiddle :

```js
$(function() {
  var i=0;
  $("#btnStart").click(function() {
    if(!i) {
      var interval = setInterval(  executeQuery, 1000);
      i=1;
    }
  });
});

var i=0;
function executeQuery() {
   var rows = "<tr>" + "<td> url" + i++ + "</td>" + "<td> key" + i + "</td>" + "<td> date " + i + "</td>" + "<td> count " + i + "<td/>" + "</tr>";
  $("#scrapTable tbody").append(rows);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnStart">Start</button>

<table  id="scrapTable" >
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```